Bluetooth Audio Issue with A2DP Profile on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I'm encountering an issue with my Bluetooth neckband on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and I’m hoping someone might be able to help.
When I connect my Realme neckband, I see two profiles in the sound settings:
Headset - Realme Buds Wireless 3 (A2DP Profile)
Handsfree - Realme Buds Wireless Free (HFP/HSP Profile)
Issue:
Handsfree mode works fine, and I can hear sound through the speakers without any problems.
Headset mode, which is supposed to provide high-fidelity audio (A2DP profile), is not producing any sound. The audio is completely muted when this profile is selected.
What I’ve Tried:
Verified Bluetooth Profile: I’ve checked and ensured that the A2DP profile is selected in the PulseAudio Volume Control (pavucontrol).
Restarted Services: Restarted both PulseAudio and the Bluetooth service.
Re-Paired the Device: Removed and re-paired the Bluetooth neckband.
Updated System: Made sure my system is up-to-date with the latest packages and drivers.
Checked Codecs: Confirmed that necessary codecs are installed and up-to-date.
Additional Info:
I can hear sound perfectly when using the Handsfree mode.
The issue started occurring after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS from a previous version.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions for further troubleshooting? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

From what previous version?


The microphone with Handsfree or Headset is pretty bad, it sounds like those old dial-up internet sounds.
I've made several modifications,
sudo apt install pulseaudio pavucontrol pulseaudio-module-bluetooth blueman 

and put it in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
AutoConnect=true

and changed
MultiProfile = multiple

but even so, the High Fidelity Playback A2DP Sink doesn't appear in the Ubuntu 24 settings. The thing is, A2DP appears in Blueman, and even though the system tells me A2DP isn't working, it seems working.
